Svelte, Snapshot & Cannot destructure property error
I am creating a Svelte application using Firebase Database and am trying to convert a simple Firebase call to use a Query Snapshot, rather than a Get, so that I can instantly see changes on screen if the database changes.
I have some working code but it is currently not updating as I need it to and when I use the Query Snapshot code it stops working almost completely. For the purposes of this - I am simply trying to get a list of Users from the database and display them on a page, which updates if any new users are added or details are changed without the need to refresh. I will list both the working and non-working code below:
Working Code
allUsersStore.JS
import { fetchUsers } from "@api/allUsers";
import { onMount } from "svelte";
import { writable } from "svelte/store"

export function allUsersStore() {

    const users = writable([]);
    const loading = writable(false);
 

   
    onMount(loadUsers);
    
    async function loadUsers() {
    loading.set(true);
try{

   const {users: theUsers} = await fetchUsers();
   
   
   
//  console.log(theUsers)

  users.set(theUsers);



} catch(e) {
console.log("ERROR!" + e.message);
}

finally {
loading.set(false);
}



       
    }
    
    
    
 
    
    return {
    //  assignedUser: { subscribe: assignedUser.subscribe },
    users: { subscribe: users.subscribe },
    loading: { subscribe: loading.subscribe },
       // users
    
    }
    
    }

allUsers.js
import { db } from "@db/index";
import { getCountFromServer, Timestamp, doc, collection, getDocs, query, addDoc, orderBy, getDoc, where, setDoc, onSnapshot, updateDoc, deleteDoc, arrayUnion, arrayRemove } from "firebase/firestore";
async function fetchUsers() {

 const q = query(collection(db, "userData"), orderBy('fullName', 'asc'));
 const qSnapshot = await getDocs(q);
 
 const users = qSnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
     const user = doc.data();
    
     return {...user, id: doc.id}
 });


 return {users};
 
 
 }

+page.svelte
<script>
import { allUsersStore } from "@stores/allUsersStore";
const { users, loading} = allUsersStore();
</script>

{#each $users as user (user.id)}
<h2>{user.fullName} </h2>
{/each}


This code works fine to produce a list of Usernames but, as I mentioned above, it will not update if a change to the database is made. As I come from an IOS background I know about Query Snapshots so I tried to implement that solution. All I changed was the call on the allUsers.js page as below:
async function fetchUsers() {

  const q = query(collection(db, "userData"), orderBy('fullName', 'asc'));
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    const users = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        users.push(doc.data());
    });

    
  for (const x of $users) {

console.log(x.fullName)

}



return {users};

  });



}

The console.log is showing the list of users names and I can see this list updating when I trigger a change in the database, however I am now getting an error from the try/catch block on allUsersStore.JS and no list is produced on my +page.svelte. The error is:
Cannot destructure property 'users' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined
Could some kind person please explain to me what I am doing wrong and if there is a better practice for what I am trying to achieve please?
Thanks in advance :)

With the code you have now, you return {users} from your onSnapshot-listener. That makes no sense. Also note that you probably can't use .forEach() to populate the array the way you want, since it will run asynchronously. To listen for data like this, your best option might be to pass along a callback function to fetchUsers(), and which you call each time your onSnapshos-listener has been called.

Thanks for your reply! I noticed shortly after my post I had written the return {users} in the wrong place. I also had the thought that I should be listening to changes & calling fetchUsers() when a change is made but I have had several attempts at this and the code is getting so messy when I know there must be a simpler way. Thanks for trying to help all the same :)

You can do something like this:
function listenForUsers(onUsersFetched){
    
    const q = query(collection(db, "userData"), orderBy('fullName', 'asc'));
    
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
        
        const fetchedUsers = querySnapshot.docs
        
        onUsersFetched(fetchedUsers)
        
    });
    
    return unsubscribe
    
}

// Then use it like this in Svelte components:
let users = []

onMount(() => {
    
    const unsubscribe = listenForUsers(
        fetchedUsers => users = fetchedUsers
    )
    
    // The function we return from onMount() will
    // run when the component is destroyed, and we
    // need to stop listening for users when that
    // happens, so simply return unsubscribe.
    return unsubscribe
    
})

You probably also want to handle errors in some way too, so most likely you also want to pass listenForUsers() an onError() callback and call that one when an error occurs, or similar.
